# How to properly implement a hash-map/do I even need one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hashmap

I am trying to use ChartsJS to great a graph of followers over time.
I already have the graph working using a less efficient method.

Data: A row of dates (when each follow happened)

```
dates = ['Mar 15', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 18', 'Mar 18']
```

The graph takes an array of dates and a value at each date.

The goal is to get the above to look like the following:

```
graph = [['Mar 14','Mar 15', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 17', 'Mar 18'],[0,1,2,2,4]]
```

So right now, my program starts at the first date in graph and checks if there are values in dates that match, then it increments the value stored.

After doing some research, I think I should be using a hash-map to make this more efficient, but I can't wrap my head around how I'd actually do it.

I don't particularly need code snippets in your answer, just a quick explanation of what I actually should be doing.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous as to where the data is coming from. Please show that, with code if you have any

Comment: The example array 'dates' is exactly what my data could look like. The start and end points for the 'graph' array I can set as anything

Comment: Right, you start with the `dates` array, but where does the 'follow' data come from? your database? And where does the `dates` array come from? Also your database? What I'm getting at is I think I need to see your Rails controller and view template

Comment: The dates array comes from a ruby injection, I'll get in a second just stepped out for a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: According to your comments, this data is coming from your Rails backend. Instead of manipulating it in the frontend it will be better to set this up in Rails.

For example, you can do

```
follow_count_on_dates = @follows.map {|f| f.created_at.change(hour: 0)}.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|follow_date,hash| hash[follow_date.strftime("%b %d")]+=1 }
```

Which will get you a hash that looks like

```
{"Mar 19"=>32, "Mar 05"=>2, "Apr 04"=>1, "May 01"=>2, "Apr 06"=>1, "Apr 21"=>1, "Apr 22"=>1, "May 04"=>3}
```

which you can then inject into your DOM and use in JS

---

#### Explanation

First we map your `@follows` ActiveRecord object so that the `created_at` property has the exact same hour, so we can work with days only. This returns an array of dates with lots of repeated ones. Then chained to that we call `each_with_object` to iterate using a Hash that initializes with `0` (the object we send in) setting the key to your `created_at` object parsed with `strftime("%b %d")` and incrementing the value inside (which starts at zero thanks to passing `Hash.new(0)` every time we see another equal date.

By the way, shouldn't you use strftime with a year value as well?

Comment: The thing is I don't have the data in that format yet which is what Im trying to do!

Comment: To convert your two arrays you'd simply iterate over them and do hash[arr1] = arr2. I'll show it in my answer in a bit

Comment: Just saw your edit, my goal is to get 'a' from your edit!
Im sorry if I didnt make that clear in my post. 
'data' comes from the following: <%=raw follow.created_at.strftime("%b %d") %>, ie. count the follows at each date

Comment: @user2886057 Ok, I have an idea of what you're doing now. Please check the edit. All of this is stuff that would have been nice to have in the original question

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a JavaScript Object. From your example:

```
graph = { 
   'Mar 14': 0,
   'Mar 15': 1,
   'Mar 16': 2,
   'Mar 17': 2,
   'Mar 18': 4
};
```

You can then loop over the keys using `for (var date in graph) {...}`.

EDIT: Based on the comments, the question seems be related to actually computing the graph value.

One approach to the problem would be to first computing the array of dates `['Mar 14', 'Mar 15', ..., 'Mar 18']`. How best to do this depends on how big the range of days can be (i.e., can it span different months?). You might want to represent the days in a different way which makes this easier to compute. Let's call this array `dateRange`.

Second, you can parse the array to create a map from each day to the number of follows that happened on that day. I.e.

```
var follows = {};
for (var date in dates) {
  if (follows[date]) {
    follows[date] += 1;
  } else {
    follows[date] = 1;
  }
}
```

Using this you can the second array by keeping a running sum:

```
var sum = 0;
var sums = [];
for (var dates in dateRange) {
   if (dates in follows) {
      sum += follows[dates];
   }
   sums.push(sum);
}
```

With this sum will contain the followers corresponding to the range of dates created in step one.

Comment: The thing is I don't have the data in that format yet which is what Im trying to do!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what kind of transformation you're trying to do? Are you trying to map the date to the index it occurs in the initial `data` array?

Comment: I'm trying to go from the 'data' array to the 'graph' array by counting the amount of followers on each particular date and adding it to the total. The total is what the subarray [0,1,2,2,4] is keeping track of

Comment: Right this makes the question a fair bit more complicated. I'll update my answer with a high level explanation.